# Table Name with more than 30 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in a MySQL database. The name of the table is more than 30 characters long 
and I want to make the same table in Oracle 11g, but Oracle only allows tables with a maximum of 30 characters in the name.
I can't change the name of the table to make it less than 30 charachters, because the system is based on these tables, and it will cost me a lot if I change the name, so changing the table name is not the answer I am looking for.

There is a table called `user_tables`, and when I describe the table it says the the `table_name` field has a datatype `varchar2(30)`, so I tried to alter the table and make the `table_name varchar2(255)` but I couldn't, it gives me an error saying:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I am connect as `sys`.

Does anyone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Don't know if synonyms support characters over 30; but it may be a work around. The functional maximum length of the synonym name is 32 bytes. Names longer than 30 bytes are permitted for Java functionality only. If you specify a name longer than 30 bytes, then Oracle Database encrypts the name and places a representation of the encryption in the data dictionary. The actual encryption is not accessible, and you cannot use either your original specification or the data dictionary representation as the synonym name.[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_7001.htm)

Comment: `user_tables` is part of the data dictionary, a set of read-only tables and views. You can not update any of the objects in the data dictionary.

Comment: And if you could update the system tables you have absolutely no idea what effect it might have on every other system table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**All Oracle identifiers are limited to 30 characters.** There is no option that lets you change that.

Answer (score 3):

Synonyms will NOT work: [source](http://www.scribd.com/doc/27576590/Synonyms-Synonyms-In-Oracle).  Limits of 30 are hard and fast.

EDIT:
After continued research [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm) Unless java is in place here per comments even a synonym will not work to allow the exceeding of 30 characters.

Long story Short: You can't do what you want to do in the oracle environment.