# DbUnit NoSuchTableException - Workaround for long table names in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, dbunit

I'm working on creating a test suite that runs on multiple databases using dbunit xml.  Unfortunately, yesterday I discovered that some table names in our schema are over 30 characters, and are truncated for Oracle.  For example, a table named `unusually_long_table_name_error` in mysql is named `unusually_long_table_name_erro` in Oracle.  This means that my dbunit file contains lines like `<unusually_long_table_name_error col1="value1" col2="value2 />`.  These lines throw a `NoSuchTableException` when running the tests in Oracle.

Is there a programmatic workaround for this?  I'd really like to avoid generating special xml files for Oracle.  I looked into a custom `MetadataHandler` but it returns lots of `java.sql` datatypes that I don't know how to intercept/spoof.  I could read the xml myself, truncate each table name to 30 characters, write that out to a temp file or `StringBufferInputStream` and then use that as input to my DataSetBuilder, but that seems like a whole lot of steps to accomplish very little.  Maybe there's some ninja Oracle trick with synonyms or stored procedures or goodness-know-what-else that could help me.  Is one of these ideas clearly better than the others?  Is there some other approach that would blow me away with its simplicity and elegance?  Thanks!

Comment: kindly check whether you can use wrapper function similar to the one in the link in mysql http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/02/05/create-a-synonym-in-mysql/

Comment: My understanding, from [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701479/table-name-with-more-than-30-characters) and its [source link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/27576590/Synonyms-Synonyms-In-Oracle) is that a synonym over 30-characters is unusable due to automatic renaming conventions.  Stored Procedures and functions are also limited to 30 characters.  So it appears that that approach won't work here.

Comment: My point is to use something like synonym in MYSQL not ORACLE

Comment: Mysql already allows table names with more than 30 characters, so I don't have any problem with it.  My tests run fine on Mysql and SQL Server, but Oracle has different table names (truncated to fit in the 30 character limit), so my dbunit .xml files don't work with it.

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work what I meant was create view or synonym in source database with table name as first thirty characters of table name and then create table  in oracle with table name as first thirty characters of source database table so u can export the views or synonyms and import them as table in oracle

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  Modify the other DBs so they respect 30-character synonyms for the longer table names.  That would work, but would requrie me to edit / recreate all of my existing .xml files.  I went with the hacky real-time modification of the xml InputStream. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of the lack of answers, I ended up going with my own suggested approach, which

1. Reads the .xml file
2. Regex's out the table name
3. Truncates the table name if it's over 30 characters
4. Appends the (potentially modified) line to a StringBuilder
5. Feeds that StringBuilder into a ByteArrayInputStream, suitable for passing into a DataSetBuilder

---

```
public InputStream oracleWorkaroundStream(String fileName) throws IOException
{
  String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

  // This pattern isolates the table name from the rest of the line
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s*<)(\\w+)(.*/>)");

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  // Use a StringBuidler for better performance over repeated concatenation
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fis.available()*2);

  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
  BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(isr);
  while (buff.ready())
  {
    // Read a line from the source xml file
    String line = buff.readLine();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    // See if the line contains a table name
    if (matcher.matches())
    {
      String tableName = matcher.group(2);
      if (tableName.length() > 30)
      {
        tableName = tableName.substring(0, 30);
      }

      // Append the (potentially modified) line
      sb.append(matcher.group(1));
      sb.append(tableName);
      sb.append(matcher.group(3));
    }
    else
    {
      // Some lines don't have tables names (<dataset>, <?xml?>, etc.)
      sb.append(line);
    }
    sb.append(ls);
  }

  return new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

EDIT: Swtiched to StringBuilder from repeated String concatenation, which gives a huge performance boost